# WPCLI - update plugins, themes, and core, all in one row, instead 3 rows?

Tags: wp-cli

Is there a way to update plugins, themes, and core, all in one row, instead 3 rows, in WPCLI?

This is the current code I use in the `crontab` and that I'd like to improve:

```
0 0 * * * for dir in /var/www/html/*/; do cd "$dir" && /usr/local/bin/wp plugin update --all --allow-root; done
0 0 * * * for dir in /var/www/html/*/; do cd "$dir" && /usr/local/bin/wp core update --allow-root; done
0 0 * * * for dir in /var/www/html/*/; do cd "$dir" && /usr/local/bin/wp theme update --all --allow-root; done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run a script instead:

```
0 0 * * * for dir in /var/www/html/*/; do cd "$dir" && ./updatewp.sh; done
```

In `updatewp.sh`:

```
wp core update --all --allow-root
wp plugin update --all --allow-root
wp theme update --all --allow-root
```

Comment: Or, perhaps even better, include the `for dir ...` in the script, and use WP-CLI's `--path` argument (eg, `wp core udpate --all --allow-root --path=$dir`).

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
0 0 * * * for dir in /var/www/html/*/; do cd "$dir" &&  \
( \
    /usr/local/bin/wp core update --allow-root && \
    /usr/local/bin/wp plugin update --all --allow-root && \
    /usr/local/bin/wp theme update --all --allow-root \
); \
done
```

`\` used to break lines up for readability; this should probably be a single line in your crontab, like so:

```
0 0 * * * for dir in /var/www/html/*/; do cd "$dir" && ( /usr/local/bin/wp core update --allow-root && /usr/local/bin/wp plugin update --all --allow-root && /usr/local/bin/wp theme update --all --allow-root ); done
```

I haven't tested this. However, I regularly do this from the command line (ie, not in crontab).